# ASP.NET MVC 3 Charting and HTTPPOST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Working in Asp.Net MVC 3.

Controller Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyChart(string sDate)
    {
        /*Call Entity Database*/
        Contact_Center_DashboardEntities3 db = new Contact_Center_DashboardEntities3();
        var results01 = db.sp_Report_Hybrid_Metrics("9 September", sDate, "Auto", "R2/R8", "Claims", "Claims", "R02_R08.AUTO.CLM.FMN.Q").ToList();


        var chart = new Chart();
        chart.Width = 1000;
        chart.Height = 200;

        var area = new ChartArea();
        // configure your chart area (dimensions, etc) here.
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

        area.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

        area.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

        area.AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        area.AxisY2.LabelStyle.Format = "0%";

        // create and customize your data series.
        var series = new Series();
        foreach (var item in results01)
        {
            series.Points.AddXY(item.Date, item.Volume);
        }
        series.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.0f, FontStyle.Bold);
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        series.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;


        // create and customize your data series.
        var seriesSecondary = new Series();
        foreach (var item in results01)
        {
            seriesSecondary.Points.AddXY(item.Date, item.XferPer);
        }
        seriesSecondary.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.0f, FontStyle.Bold);
        seriesSecondary.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        seriesSecondary.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        seriesSecondary.LabelFormat = "0%";
        seriesSecondary.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;


        chart.Series.Add(series);
        chart.Series.Add(seriesSecondary);

        var returnStream = new MemoryStream();
        chart.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
        chart.SaveImage(returnStream);
        returnStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(returnStream, "image/png");

    }
```

Tables View Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyChart", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="submit" value="09/06/2014" name = "sDate"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

}
```

When the user clicks the Submit button, the value passes to the "MyChart" ActionResult correctly, but then takes me to the MyChart view.  What I need it to do is pass the value through, stay on the Tables View, and refresh the chart.

Comment: Did you try Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea how to use that.  I know StackOverflow isn't for step-by-step hand holding instructions, but can you give examples if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyChart", "Home", new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod= "Post", UpdateTargetId = "chartContainer", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="submit" value="09/06/2014" name = "sDate"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

<div id="chartContainer">
</div>
```

The request is done by ajax and inserts the response of the request into the element addressed by updatetargetid. If the submit button should be deleted after clicking it once, place the form inside the div. Otherwise the chart would be refreshed overtime you press the submit-button.

Comment: tried that, but was getting "AjaxOptions" does not contain reference to "FormMethod" error.  Web.config file has System.Web.Mvc.Ajax and I tried including it at the beginning of the view as well.

Comment: Sorry. Didn#t have a visual studio. Don't you have intellisense? ;-) It has to be HttpMethod and InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace.